# SuppressMessageAttribute; suppressing all warnings within a class

Tags: .net

As the question states; is it possible to suppress all specified warmings that appears within a class? I've been trying out attributes along the lines of:

```
namespace Testing2k.Collections
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a collection that utilizes an array internally to store it's content.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"> The type of elements contained in the collection. </typeparam>

    [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1800", Justification = "Choosing readability over a trivial optimalization.", Target = "Testing2k.Collections.ArrayBasedCollection<T>")]
    public abstract class ArrayBasedCollection<T> : ArrayBasedStructure<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

None of them seem to do anything, so I'm wondering what the correct way to do it is, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have it mostly right.

[SuppressMessageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute.aspx) has a `[Conditional("CODE_ANALYSIS")]` attribute applied to it, so make sure you have defined the `CODE_ANALYSIS` conditional compilation symbol.

In addition, you can try changing that `"CA1800"` to `"CA1800:DoNotCastUnnecessarily"`.